# What are the downsides of using utm tracking parameters in og:url?

Tags: seo, tracking, meta-tags, canonical-link, utm

I'm wondering whether to use utm tracking parameters in the og and twitter meta data URLs. I notice that sites like Mashable, Techcrunch, and Buzzfeed do not, and I question why that would be. They just use the canonical URLs for og:url and twitter:url.

It seems like, obviously, you'd be able to track traffic better with tracking parameters in the URLs. Why even include the og and twitter URLs as separate tags if they are no different than the canonical URL?

I guess one downside is that Facebook might not track Likes properly if Likes are split among the canonical URL and the URLs with parameters?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Here's one opinion on this on Quora: http://www.quora.com/Can-it-hurt-search-ranking-by-having-a-different-og-url-from-my-canonical-url-We-added-a-tracking-parameter-to-our-og-url-to-better-track-facebook-traffic-but-i-wonder-if-it-hurt-us-in-search-referrals-if-the-google-bing-algorithms-are-using-number-of-likes-on-the-canonical-url-as-a-factor

Comment: This site seems to indicate that og:url is functioning as a canonical url for Facebook so that all interactions like Likes, etc. can be aggregated: http://qnimate.com/open-graph-protocol-in-facebook/

Comment: Ok, KISSmetrics suggests as well that the purpose of og:url is to set the canonical URL for Likes and other interactions: https://blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/